# Typescript/Webpack: cannot find module 'react-select'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I'm trying to set up React with typescript, i followed the tutorial [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html). I installed `react-select` but when i try to reference it i get a compiler error `Build: Cannot find module 'react-select'`, i get the same error if i try to run webpack from the cmd line.

I tried including the following loader as suggested as a fix on github but I get the same error.

```
 {
    test: /\.js$/,
    include: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'react-select'),
    loader: 'jsx-loader',
  }
```

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "jsx": "react"
    },
    "files": [
        "./typings/index.d.ts",
        "./src/components/Hello.tsx",
        "./src/index.tsx"
    ]
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "react-typescript-setup",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "./dist/bundle.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "webpack": "webpack -w"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.1",
    "react-select": "^1.0.0-rc.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "react-select": "^1.0.0-rc.1",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.1.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "ts-loader": "^0.8.2",
    "typings": "^1.3.3"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.tsx",
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "./dist/bundle.js",
    },

    // Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
    devtool: "source-map",
    debug: true,

    resolve: {
        // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
        extensions: ["", ".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'ts-loader'.
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "ts-loader" },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style!css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
            }
        ],

        preLoaders: [
            // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
            { test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
        ]
    },

    // When importing a module whose path matches one of the following, just
    // assume a corresponding global variable exists and use that instead.
    // This is important because it allows us to avoid bundling all of our
    // dependencies, which allows browsers to cache those libraries between builds.
    externals: {
        "react": "React",
        "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
    },
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to install the typings for `react-select` in order to import it. Once you do that go to the installed typings and check the type of export being done.

In case it is something like `export = Select` you need to do `import = require('react-select')`

In case it is something like `export default Select` you need to do `import Select from`react-select`

In case of named exports i.e `export {Select}` you need to do `import {Select} from 'react-select'`

In case of multiple named exports you will have to explicitly import each export or do `import * as Select from 'react-select'`

According to the typings for `react-select` as shown [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/react-select/react-select-0.9.10.d.ts) the module exports its contents through a default export at the bottom of the file. So `import ReactSelect from 'react-select'` should work for you

Comment: The typings are now baked into the react-select package, so no need to install @types/react-select any more..

Answer (score 3):

I was looking at my packges and I found that `react-select` package is missing from `@types` in `node_modules`, so I ran this command `# npm install --save @types/react-select` and it solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Configuring Typsecript with `webpack` should be defined something like that:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./app/boot",
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "./dist/bundle.js"
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.ts/,   loader: ["ts-loader"], exclude: /node_modules/ },
    ],
    preLoaders: [
      // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader", exclude: ['node_modules', 'ext-*', 'lib', 'tools'] }
    ]
  },
  debug: true,
  devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

The `ts-loader` loads the enables the Typescript to the browser and the `source-map-loader` loads the source-maps to the browser for easier debugging.

Let me know if you need anything or if I misunderstood you.

Comment: Hmm, that's pretty much what i have, i just installed the typings for react-select, that's changed the error, now it says it cannot be imported using this construct..

Comment: what is >this construct?

Comment: Any of the ES6 import statement, Import * as Select, Import Select from, import { Select } from ..

Comment: but it works if i use require.. `
import Select = require("react-select");`

Comment: Is your environment configured to use es6 syntax ?

Comment: yeah it is, have had it all working fine before trying it out with typescript now and it's proving to be a nightmare

Comment: Can you add an image of how it is configured?

Comment: I'll ad some into my question now

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by pointing into the dist file:

```
import CreatableSelect from "react-select/creatable/dist/react-select-creatable.cjs";
```